# Evaluate the flux of the vector field $\vec F = -9\hat j- 3 \hat k$ on the surface $z=y$ bounded by the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=16$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

> Evaluate the flux of the vector field $\vec F = -9\hat j- 3 \hat k$ on the surface $z=y$ bounded by the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=16$

**My attempt:**

$$\iint_S \vec F \cdot \vec n dS = \iint_S (0,-9,-3) \cdot (0,1,-1) dS = -6\iint_S  dS = -6A$$

Where $A$ is the area of the surface.

$A$ equal to the area of a circle with radius $4$, so $A= \pi \cdot 4^2 = 16 \pi$

Therefore the flux is:
$$\iint_S \vec F \cdot \vec n dS = -6A = -96\pi$$

But the correct answer is $-48 \sqrt{2}\pi$.

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\vec{n}$ should have a unitary norm, so you need to divide your answer by $\sqrt{2}$ (which is equivalent to multiplying by $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$).

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,\mathrm{Li}}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
The 'intersection' is given by
$\ds{16 = x^{2} + y^{2} + y^{2} = x^{2} + 2y^{2}\ \imp
1 = {x^{2} \over \color{#f00}{4}^{2}} + {y^{2} \over \pars{\color{#f00}{2\root{2}}}^{2}}}$. The area you are looking for is given by $\ds{\pi \times \color{#f00}{4} \times \color{#f00}{2\root{2}} = 8\pi\root{2}}$ which yields
$$
\pars{8\pi\root{2}}\pars{-6} = \color{#f00}{-48\pi\root{2}}
$$